# Unable to install React JS in my Windows X64

Tags: reactjs

[trying to install using npx command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J5hb.png)...I tried installing React JS using these commands...but its not installing react after last two lines in the image.

Comment: Please help me resolve this problem

Comment: No need to beg, we're here to help. Did you log into the system as an administrator?

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to be stopping the react install, just the npm update checking procedure

Comment: Try `npx create-react-app <app-name>` instead. You may need to uninstall it locally `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` though.

Comment: thanks....i am able to install it now

Answer (score -1):

Try running cmd as administrator.

Comment: If you are still facing issues installing react, try reinstalling latest version of node and then try `npx create-react-app <app-name>`.

Comment: my node js is a latest one v13.13.0